# Convert List<string> to JSON using C# and Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a List that I would like to convert to JSON using C# and Newtonsoft.

tags

```
[0]: "foo"
[1]: "bar"
```

Output to be:-

```
{"tags": ["foo", "bar"]}
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction please? I can convert the List to JSON okay but they key thing here is I need the "tags" part in the JSON which I do not get with a convert using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tags)`.

Comment: Sorry.. first time use. The List should be tags: [0] "Foo" [1] "Bar"

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46277282/edit) your own posts. Also you may want to read the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The below code wraps the list in an anonymous type, and thus generates what you are looking for.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<string> {"foo", "bar"};

            var tags = new {tags = list};

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tags));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Arguably the easiest way to do this is to just write a wrapper object with your `List<string>` property

```
public class Wrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("tags")]
    public List<string> Tags {get; set; }
}
```

And then when serialized this gives the output you expect.

```
var obj = new Wrapper(){ Tags = new List<string>(){ "foo", "bar"} };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
Console.WriteLine(json);
// outputs: {"tags":["foo","bar"]}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/FTFIBT36362

Answer (score 3):

Use like this.

```
var data = new { tags = new List<string> { "foo", "bar" } };
var str = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

**Output:**

{"tags": ["foo","bar"] }

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate class like this:

```
public class TagList
{
    [JsonProperty("tags")]
    List<string> Tags { get; set; }

    public TagList(params string[] tags)
    {
        Tags = tags.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then call:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new TagList("Foo", "Bar"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [anonymous object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) to wrap your list like that:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {Tags = tags});
```

Comment: This is a neat trick that works for a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this.

```
static void  Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> messages = new List<string>();
        messages.Add("test");
        messages.Add("test 2");
        Items data = new Items { items = messages };
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        JObject jo = JObject.Parse(output);
        Console.WriteLine(jo);
    }

public class Items
{
   public List<string> items { get; set; }
}
```

Produces:

```
{
  "items": [
    "test",
    "test 2"
  ]
}
```